# CkEditor - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am implementing the `CKEditor` in my app. When I am trying to instantiate `CKEditor` to the textarea I am getting following error

```
Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined
```

at below line of ckeditor

```
getNative: function() {
 return void 0 !== this._.cache.nativeSel ? this._.cache.nativeSel : this._.cache.nativeSel = B ? this.document.$.selection : this.document.getWindow().$.getSelection() }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

1. I have a list of articles.
2. every time I clicked on any article a "dialog / modal" should be open.
3. in such dialog or modal there was a ckeditor element for the content of my article.
4. when I clicked on the first it worked like a charm.
5. the problem was after clicking on the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc.

Then I started to have this error.

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined
    at CKEDITOR.dom.selection.getNative (ckeditor.js:448)
    at new CKEDITOR.dom.selection (ckeditor.js:446)
    at a.CKEDITOR.editor.getSelection (ckeditor.js:443)
    at new CKEDITOR.plugins.undo.Image (ckeditor.js:1182)
    at CKEDITOR.plugins.undo.UndoManager.save (ckeditor.js:1177)
    at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:1173)
    at a.n (ckeditor.js:10)
    at a.CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
    at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13)
    at a.setData (ckeditor.js:275)
```

The solution for me was easy, **tell the computer to destroy the ckeditor instance when the dialog / modal is closed**. easy!..
Now is working like a charm =)

```
           $mdDialog.show({
             parent:      parentEl,
             targetEvent: $event,
             templateUrl: '/md-templates/blog-article.html',
             controller:  DialogController,
             scope:         $scope,
             preserveScope: true,
            onRemoving: function (event, removePromise) {
                if (CKEDITOR.instances.body) CKEDITOR.instances.body.destroy();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I spent 20 mins writing my above instructions and a genius put it minus??.. you should see my script working. how can I report to stackoverflow? this?..

Comment: I used your code successfully, except for whatever reason, it worked much better inside of `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

I got same error, and I solved by initialize CKEditor, in 
`$(document).function(ready());`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
        language: 'tr',
        height: '300'
    });
});
```

I think when you initialize before page load, it doesn't find dom element(textarea)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely your application is attempting to access and set the data of the CKEditor before the editor is ready. This can be the result of a race condition, causing the error to be intermittent. There are a few things you can do to prevent this issue.

First, the [CKEditor endorsed](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#property-status) method of testing if the editor is `loaded` first.

```
if ( CKEDITOR.status == 'loaded' ) {
    // The API can now be fully used.
    doSomething();
} else {
    // Wait for the full core to be loaded and fire its loading.
    CKEDITOR.on( 'load', doSomething );
    CKEDITOR.loadFullCore && CKEDITOR.loadFullCore();
}
```

Second, if you are unable to control the timing associated with setting of the editor value, you could wrap the `CKEDITOR.dom.window` object in an `async`/`await` `Promise` that tests if the editor is loaded first, and if not, listens for the  editor to load, and then complete setting the value. (note, this code is not fully tested)

```
CKEDITOR.dom.window = (function(window) {
    if ( CKEDITOR.status == 'loaded' ) {
        // The API can now be fully used.
        return window;
    } else {
        return (async function() {
            return await function() {
                return new Promise(resolve => {
                    CKEDITOR.on( 'load', () => {
                        resolve(window);
                    });
                });
            };
        })();

        CKEDITOR.loadFullCore && CKEDITOR.loadFullCore();
    }
})(CKEDITOR.dom.window);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before any actions with CKEDITOR, is better to check if it exists AND target input still exist. The approved answer nearly about the same - destroying an instance of unlisted anymore in DOM input

```
let inputId = "some_uniq_id";
if (
   CKEDITOR.instances[inputId]
   && !document.contains(CKEDITOR.instances[inputId].element.$)
) {
  CKEDITOR.instances[inputId].destroy();
}
if (!CKEDITOR.instances[inputId]) {
  CKEDITOR.replace(inputId, {toolbar: []});
}
CKEDITOR.instances[inputId].setData('<p>Some nice text =*</p>')
// setData as example in my case
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be late to the answer but will give respect to angular
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy();
keep these in the methods required
For newer Versions
Firstly Console.log(CKEDITOR) and see the methods and destroy the instances

Answer (score -1):

You can have a try

`CKEditor.destroy();`

Answer (score -5):

change the function f.$.onload inside ckeditor.js to the below

```
 f.$.onload=function(){var toutMs =5000;
    if(CKEDITOR.document.getHead().$.childElementCount > 6)
    {
    toutMs=0;
      }
    setTimeout(function(){
    A(b,!0)
     },toutMs)
     }
```