# angular 4 ckeditor - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I am implementing ckeditor for my angular 4 application. Everything is working fine but when I came back from another page using browser back button, I am getting below error with the editor hangs

```
ckeditor.js:445 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined
at CKEDITOR.dom.selection.getNative (ckeditor.js:445)
at CKEDITOR.dom.selection (ckeditor.js:443)
at a.CKEDITOR.editor.getSelection (ckeditor.js:440)
at CKEDITOR.plugins.undo.Image (ckeditor.js:1072)
at CKEDITOR.plugins.undo.UndoManager.save (ckeditor.js:1067)
at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:1063)
at a.n (ckeditor.js:10)
at a.CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13)
at CKEDITOR.command.exec (ckeditor.js:952)
```

When I deep dive into code, I found the error is in below function where `this.document.getWindow().$` is undefined and it try to call function on that.

```
        getNative: function() {
            return void 0 !== this._.cache.nativeSel ? this._.cache.nativeSel : this._.cache.nativeSel = x ? this.document.$.selection : this.document.getWindow().$.getSelection()
        }
```

Comment: I have same error

Comment: Have you tried to clean the browser cache?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CkEditor - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005430/ckeditor-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-getselection-of-undefined)